# How to calculate/measure the spread of coordinates in an area using python

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, coordinates, spread

My question seems a little bit vague. Put it in this way:

I have a set of coordinates(latitude and longitude) in an area(a city) and I want to quantify their separation. for example, they will get a low score if they are all at the same location(actually this should be the lowest score), and they will get a high score if they are very separated. For example, if you imagine how a set of charges would arrange themselves on a circular conducting plate, that should maximise their separation- this state would get the highest "separation" score.

As I have thousands of coordinates in the area, so I want to find a very efficient way to calculate that. Another problem I am thinking about is that: my coordinates are all latitude and longitude which cannot reflect the distance in meter correspondingly (i.e., at different latitudes, same longitude difference corresponds to different distance in meter), so should I also consider this in the spread calculation?

So does anyone know of any algorithms or approaches or theory I can use to do this, in the most mathematically respectable way? I am a newbie in this concept and in python, and I appreciate it a lot if you could give me some ideas.

Thank you all, Gladys

Comment: how separate would it be for the set where it has 2 groups that are far away from the other but have a lot of points close to each other within the group... for example, a set of coordinates of `all train stations in New York + all train stations in San Francisco`? vs `all train stations in San Francisco`? or vs the sum of set1:`all train stations in New York` + set2:`all train stations in San Francisco`?

Comment: Hi Kaho, hmmm actually I only care about venues in one city, so your proposal won't happen....

Comment: Ummm.. I know that, just for an example only. I was thinking to suggest you find the avg(sum of distance from median point to each point), but if you have 2 groups like the NY SF example, the median point would be somewhere in the middle of the states, and you end up with a super huge number

Answer (score 1):

Given spherical coordinates, the distance in meters as the crow flies is computed by [orthodromic distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance). In truly urban environment the metrics is usually more convoluted. You may be forced to account for roads, public transportation, traffic variations etc.

A set of charges analogy could result in an interesting separation measure. Attach a charge to each object, and calculate total potential energy. Lower energy means better separation. You may play with laws of repulsion.

Comment: Can you give a solid link to the potential energy lead?